# Calculating a new average time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, average

I'm a beginner. I am implementing a script in C #. I want to implement a method that will allow me to retrieve data with the average time of a repetitive process.
I have data for a start time 't1' and an end time 't2' which I save in PalyerPrefs.
On the first iteration, the average time is

```
var averageTime = (t2-t1)/1;
```

I save the number of iterations 'n' in PlayerPrefs. I need to implement a method that will overwrite the average time of subsequent iterations. How to implement mean value calculation for next iteration, which I will save in variable 'savedValue'?
Successive iterations will change the mean value according to the formula:

```
var finalAverageValue = ((savedValue * n) + averageTime) / n + 1;
```

Ok, I solved my problem myself. Thanks to everyone for the answers.

Comment: why do you think you need recursion? There are three variables within your formula that all have fix values for every click. Did you encounter any specific issue with the code?

Comment: Here is a complimentary pair of parentheses: `()`. You may want to use them around the `n + 1` bit. Also, typically I think you'll get less rounding error if you just track `n` and the sum, instead of updating the average all the time.

Answer (score 0):

We can use simple math to solve this. Just divide the time when you first click and the time when you last click by the total number of clicks.

```
averageTimeBetweenClicks = timeOfLastClick - timeOfFirstClick / numberOfClicks
```

This should do the work.

Comment: Here is a complimentary pair of parentheses: `()`. You may want to use them in that calculation.